# Proving volts is related to Joules / Coulomb

Tags: energy, charge, voltage, dimensional-analysis, si-units

To prove how volts is related to energy transfer and charge you can do:

E = VIt

V = E/It

V = J/Cs<sup>-1</sup> x s

You can cancel out the seconds, leaving:

J/C

Joules per coulomb is equal to volts

This is how we've been taught, but I don't understand why for current (Cs) it is to the power of -1

Please could someone explain to me why Cs is to the power of -1?

P.S. I realise E/It is the same as E/Q, but now we have been taught like this I am intrigued.

Comment: The volt is *defined* as a joule per coulomb - it is the unit of electrostatic potential, which is defined as the potential energy per unit charge. That's not to say that there aren't meaningful connections to be made, but if you don't make it crystal clear what your starting point is (i.e. which two identities for the volt you want to connect) then you're just building a bridge from nowhere to nowhere.

Comment: I did say right at the beginning: energy transfer and charge

Comment: "related to energy transfer and charge" is *not* a sufficiently detailed specification of where you're starting from and where you want to get to.

Answer (score 1):

If you raise a number to the power of -1, you take its reciprocal, so $s^{-1}$ is the same as $1/s$. Multiplying by one Coulomb gives $C s^{-1}= C/s$. Current is charge per unit time, so this gives units of current. Your confusion is that you think it means the whole $Cs$ to the power of -1, rather than just $s$. If a unit ever ends with $s^{-1}$ it means something per second, e.g coulomb per second or metre per second.

Answer (score 0):

Energy (J) is seen as a static discharge energy.

You have C charges and you get E energy when these charges leave through V volts.

Each charge gets the energy of eV electron volt.

So   : J = n . eV 
And : C = n.e

So J = C . V

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question